# Replace slash with text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

everyone! I'm trying to replace part of url in input field with selected info from autosuggest. For example, I've got this url in box

```
http://www.example.com/SuperEx
```

Json from method give me `/NotSuper` How can I change url into

```
http://www.example.com/NotSuper
```

This is my code of autocomplete:

```
 $(function () {
        $('.MyClass4').autocomplete({
            delay: 500,
            minLength: @(Model.SearchTermMinimumLength.ToString()),
            source: '@(Url.RouteUrl("ProductSearchAutoComplete"))',
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $(".MyClass4").val(ui.item.label);
                $('.MyPic img').attr('src',ui.item.productpictureurl).width(100).height(56);
                $('.MyTxt4 input').attr('value',ui.item.label);
                return false;
            }
        })
```

Comment: What's the rule on what part to replace? Everything after the *last* slash? (Just wondering if the URL might sometimes have more parts, like `http://www.example.com/Another/Few/Bits/SuperEx`.)

Comment: Everything after the last slash, yes. URL always have this look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you expecting this solution?

If yes try with `lastIndex` method of javascript to find the last slash of your url and then slice & replace your url.

```
var str = "http://www.example.com/SuperEx"; 
var res = str.lastIndexOf('/');
var removed = str.slice(res);
var jsonVal = "/NotSuper";
var url = str.replace(removed,jsonVal);
alert(url);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Luujc43h/)

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: Yes, it helped! There is my final code `var data = $('.MyLnk1 input').val();
                    var res = data.lastIndexOf('/');
                    var removed = data.slice(res);
                    $('.MyLnk1 input').attr('value',data.replace(removed,ui.item.producturl));`